# Selenium open new tab instead of downloading

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am using **Selenium** to download mp4 movie from a website. when I use click(), it open media instead of downloading. how can I force it to download?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains as AC
driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files (x86)\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('***')

for i in range(1,53):
   click=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*@id="tabdownload"]/div[3]/div/div['+str(i)+']/div/h3/a')
   clicl.click()
```

Comment: Without seeing that site we can't help you

Comment: can you share the link?

Comment: this is a gerneral concern and I've faced in different sites. here is the link : https://2zabanesho.com/50/